# Неправильное отображение border у псевдоэлементов в Google Chrome

Tags: html, css, псевдоэлемент

```css
.separator {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.separator::before,
.separator::after {
  content: "";
  flex: 1;
  /* для того, чтобы сепараторы занимали все свободное пространство */
  border: 1px solid #EEBF3A;
}
```

```html
<div class="separator bg-grey">
  <div class="separator-icon home-icon"></div>
</div>
```

Как это выглядит в Firefox (все правильно):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И в Google Chrome:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Наверное плохо видно, поэтому вот кроп:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У псевдоэлементов появляется высота и сепараторы получаются расслоенными. Как это исправить? Возможно какой-то сброс стилей прописать?

Comment: В моих Firefox и Chrome этот пример выглядит одинаково правильно

Comment: хмм, вот приколюха, и что с моим Chrome не так))

Comment: я нашел решение, но через костыль. Если прописать border-top: 2px, то в обоих браузерах будет выглядть одинаково, но тогда сепаратор сместится вверх на 1 пиксель и уже не будет идеально посередине

Comment: вот такой прикол, я открыл этот вопрос в Chrome, выполнил этот код из моего вопроса и тут тоже сепаратор расслаивается

Comment: Версия браузера, версия ОС, масштаб страницы, установленные расширения?

Comment: 87 версия, масшаб 100%, расширения: comment filter BY (вряд ли о нем кто-то знает не из Беларуси) и Perfect Pixel by WellDoneCode

Comment: height: 0 не решает проблемы

Comment: ааа да, еще вариант, прописать background-color, но тогда в Firefox толщина сепаратора будет 2 px, а в Chrome - уже 3

Comment: Ах да, в самой системе масштаб интерфейса какой? Дисплей обычный или с высокой плотностью пикселей?

Comment: 125% Дисплей 1920 на 1080

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не думал, что возникнет такая проблема. Действительно, Chrome (v 87.0.4280.141) рендерит так, что появляется зазор на масштабах 125, 150, 175 и 250 процентов. При этом, Firefox (v 84.0.2) всё отображает корректно, даже с масштабом 133%.

> еще вариант, прописать background-color, но тогда в Firefox толщина сепаратора будет 2 px

Она и так 2px должна быть, потому что толщина *border* равна 1px, но *border*-а два - *top* и *bottom*. И, если Firefox отображает только 1px, то тогда уже этот браузер неверно рендерит.

Поэтому, просто меняем *border* на *background-color* и ставим `height: 2px;` - должно максимально одинаково отображаться в любом браузере:

```css
.separator {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.separator::before,
.separator::after {
  content: "";
  flex: 1; /* для того, чтобы сепараторы занимали все свободное пространство */
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #EEBF3A;
}
```

```html
<div class="separator bg-grey">
  <div class="separator-icon home-icon"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Я знаю что она должна быть 2px :) Но в хроме то 3px...

Comment: Ты гений, спасибо!

Comment: @hot_penguin: вообще оба браузера ведут себя не совсем правильно.